# Optimize JPA dynamic count query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa, eclipselink

Having the typical method which returns a paginated result, using `CriteriaBuilder` and performing 2 queries:

- one that counts the total number of results
- and another one that gives us the subset for the specified page

We have noticed that the first query, JPA does not optimize it at all because it's using the [exists](https://www.educba.com/oracle-exists/) (from Oracle).

Java code:

```
Root<Foo> from = criteriaQuery.from(Foo.class);
//... predicates
CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class)
        .select(criteriaBuilder.countDistinct(from))
        .where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
Long numberResults = entityManager.createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult();
```

SQL generated query:

```
SELECT COUNT(t0.REFERENCE) 
FROM foo t0 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT t1.REFERENCE 
  FROM foo t1 
  WHERE ((((t0.REFERENCE = t1.REFERENCE) AND (t0.VERSION_NUM = t1.VERSION_NUM)) AND (t0.ISSUER = t1.ISSUER)) AND (t1.REFERENCE LIKE ? AND (t1.VERSION_STATUS = ?)))
);
```

How do I avoid using the `exists`? Is there something wrong with the java code?

Comment: do you really need the countDistinct() instead of simple count() ? Looks like the REFERENCE is the PK... Try to compare with the SQL generated with count().

Comment: if you're after a better query, I think `select count(*), count(case when <your conditions> then 1 end) from <your table>;` is probably what you're after. No idea about how you'd generate that in your java/jpa/whatever code though

Comment: @p3consulting Indeed, `countDistinct()` is redundant. With `count()` only, still gives me the same query with EXISTS.

Comment: so the problem seems to come from the original predicates that are copied, in general JPQL queries are easier to master (get the SQL you want from the JPQL expression...), without speaking of native ones...

Comment: You should definitely provide the part where `//... predicates`. Also [exists](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp) operator seems to me to be standard SQL and not specific to oracle. And what makes you think that the query is not optimized? If at all, there seem to be a bunch of unnecessary `()` in the query, as you have `AND` and no `OR`. I am not that proficient with SQL, but this query `SELECT COUNT(t0.REFERENCE) FROM foo t0 WHERE t0.REFERENCE LIKE ? AND t0.VERSION_STATUS = ?` should do the same as yours from what I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For different reasons, [this issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=317777) and [this related article](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=170219&start=0) enumerate some of them, EclipseLink uses `EXISTS` in the `countDistinct` operation implementation.

Although I can agree with you, be aware that the performance offered by `EXISTS` in Oracle is in fact very dependent of the use case, and it doesn't have to be poor. Please, consider review [this mythical blog entry](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=in-vs-exists-and-not-in-vs-not-exists) in the Tom Kyte blob.

So my advice is, please, keep using the generated code and corresponding SQL.

If you need or want to use a different approach, a perhaps more performant way of counting the records could be fetching the ids of the entities that match the provided predicates (the actual performance in fact is mostly dependent on these predicates in fact), and count the results in memory, with Java. I mean:

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
// I assume reference is String here
CriteriaQuery<String> query = cb.createQuery(String.class);
Root<Foo> root = query.from(Foo.class);

query
  .select(root.get("reference"))
    .distinct(true)
  .where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]))
;
List<String> references = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
int count = references.size();
```

Although I think it is always not advisable, if the amount of data is not large, you could even fetch the results once from the database, and do the paging in memory with Java, it is straightforward using [`subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-), for instance.

At a final word, AFAIK other JPA providers such as Hibernate implements count in a different way: if switching the JPA provider is an option you could try using it instead.

Comment: Ok thanks, so it might not be as terrible as you mention. I identified that the main issue is a specific predicate that uses `LIKE`. In the example I posted, it's the part of `t1.REFERENCE LIKE ?` Reference is part of the PK. I realized that by using `=` instead, the query is much better performant.  Regarding what you say about sub-listing the result I think it's risky because the number of entries could be quite large and give us a timeout.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback @anat0lius. Yes, it makes perfect sense: using `like` will prevent the use of the primary key index. Using `=` will of course take advantage of it and the query will perform better. Yes, I agree with you: sorry, I mentioned the memory filtering with sublist just as a possible approach but, as stated in the answer as well, I think it should be only used when dealing with small datasets, in order to prevent memory or timeout related issues like the one you have indicated. When possible it is always advisable to filter the results in the database itself.

Comment: @anat0lius for completeness only, I indicated in my previous comment that using `LIKE` will prevent Oracle from using the index but in fact I should have said _probably_, because it is not always true. I searched for reference and for instance I came across [this article](https://quanwenzhao.wordpress.com/2020/03/24/optimizing-sql-with-like-expression/) which provides different use cases. I hope it helps in some way.

Comment: that's right, it's using the index in our case. We append the `%` wildcard at the end of the searching term, so there are no issues. But the article you shared mentions there is another wildcard character, the underscore `_`, and I didn't know about that... Precisely the client is using terms that contain underscores and that degrades the performance.

Comment: @anat0lius you could try escaping the underscores included in the terms provided by the client, the JPA criteria API provides mechanisms for such functionality. Please, consider review [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57628146/escape-character-in-like-through-criteria-api), I think it will be of help.

Answer (score 1):

With or without EXISTS, the query plans are identical. The only optimisation  would be to return COUNT() and the result in the same query, easy to do in SQL with "OVER()". But mapping the Foo.class on a view and adding a transient column to contain the count will complicate a lot of other parts of the application, and mapping the result of paginated queries on a new CountedFoo.class will also complicate the solution.